# sum the individual columns of 3 different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Sum the individual columns of  3 different  arrays

I need to sum the arrays of individual columns

```
$a = [1,2,3,4];
$b = [5,6,8,7];
$c = [10,11,4,70];
```

the output will be like that..

```
$d = [(1+5+10),(2+6+11),(3+8+4),(4+7+70)];
```

then $d will be

```
$d = [16,19,15,81];
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Did you even tried anything?

Comment: try using foreach

Comment: yes i tried but these arrays are created in for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4];
$b = [5,6,8,7];
$c = [10,11,4,70];
$limit = count($a);
$d = array();
for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
    $d[] = $a[$i]+$b[$i]+$c[$i];
}
var_dump($d);//array(16,19,15,81)
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Please mind use of count() function only once and then use of $limit var in for loop. In other answer there is use of : sizeof() function inside for loop, it will slow down the process as sizeof() will execute everytime for loop continues. Its a bad practice to use functions such as count() or sizeof() inside for loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = [1,2,3,4];
$b = [5,6,8,7];
$c = [10,11,4,70];
$res = [];

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($a);$i++)
{
  $res[$i]=$a[$i]+$b[$i]+$c[$i];
}
```

Comment: Its a bad practice to use functions such as count() or sizeof() inside for loop condition. Use them to store the value in some variable once and then use that variable in for loop condition otherwise it slows down the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```html
$a = [1,2,3,4];
$b = [5,6,8,7];
$c = [10,11,4,70];
$myArray = array($a, $b, $c);

$sumArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
  }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```